# Should moderators be able to post without diamonds?

Tags: discussion, moderators

On reddit, admins/moderators are able to comment with or without [A], [M] next to their names. Should SE implement this?

I think I may be against this, because I believe the community should constantly see moderators' activity, to make sure the moderators are all competent enough to understand the subject of the site, which is crucial for being a good moderator.

It is uncomfortable for the moderators, but it is their responsibility for which they should get ready when going for election.

I haven't found this question on meta, so I've posted it.

Comment: If their account is mod status then the diamond should be displayed with their posts. It allows more weight to answers, and even comments if it's of an "advisory" nature. Although, I don't think their username should carry the diamond in content they posted prior to being a mod, but that's a different kettle of fish.

Comment: My post disagrees with the proposal, like the answer, and I haven't found this proposal posted on meta and thought this should sometime be posted for others to discuss, so I don't think it deserves the downvotes.

Comment: This is Meta, where downvotes are about more than suggesting a question is just good or bad. On Meta People use votes for "yes", "no", "I agree", "I disagree", "bad question", "not useful", "no research effort", etc. I wouldn't worry about it too much. (I didn't vote either way, FWIW)

Comment: @user26486 You may be getting some reactions to your question title, but aside from that... Your post is starting a discussion for a feature that currently doesn't exist and your entire argument seems to be "I don't think it should happen". That's all well and good, but you may be attracting downvotes because it seems like you posted for the sake of posting. What's your goal here?

Comment: @AnnaLear It was an idea for a feature, and while I may disagree, someone may agree. As mentioned, some other sites use this feature, and it is something to at least consider. Since I haven't found a meta post about it, I've posted it.

Comment: @user26486 Fair enough. Unusual, though, since usually people post requests for features they *want* to see implemented. :) But there you go - in a weird way, downvotes here indicate agreement. Others evidently don't want this feature either.

Comment: A very similar question was asked on Community Building last year, if you wish to see other opinions: [Should moderators always be denoted as such to the community?](http://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/358/should-moderators-always-be-denoted-as-such-to-the-community)

Answer (score 24):

No.

This is something that's come up time and again and the consensus is that as moderators *everything* we do is filtered through that lens. It would be dishonest to post without the diamond.

If a moderator really wants to post as a regular user they can create a second account (it's not against the rules as long as they don't interact with their main account) and use that. In fact there is some benefit to doing this as you get to experience the site as a regular user and having the diamond can, and does, colour your view of the site.